# Does isNaN and NaN have a boolean

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to understand why when I put in the console
`isNaN == true` results to `false` while `!isNaN == false` returns to `true`.

When

```
NaN == true
false
NaN == false
false
```

Sorry I'm kinda new and somewhat confused.

Comment: [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) is a function... while `NaN` never equals to anything.

Comment: And a function is a truthy value.

Comment: only null, undefined, false, and 0 is FALSE in javascript

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the additional inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The isNaN()** function determines whether a value is NaN or not.

its return **true** if the given value is **NaN**; otherwise, **false**.

see below link for [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: Wow Thanks! This helped alot!

Comment: @icedogedev if its helpful thn please correct and upvote my ans...plz

Answer (score 1):

`isNaN` is a function which determines if the value is `NaN`. So `isNaN` will check if the input is  a number or not .

For example `isNaN(5) == true` will return false , because 5 is a number, Simillarly for empty string `isNaN('') == true` will also return false it is not a number.
But for i`sNaN('Hello') == tru`e will return `true`, since 'Hello' is not a number

Now when using `negation(!)` it will work oppositely

Comment: *Note:* `isNaN(true)` is `false`, same for `false`